# Error in Connection Testing in Mule Database connector

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-esb

I am trying to connect mysql database with mulesoft database connector, but it is giving error while I do test Connection. I am not able to figure out what is wrong I am doing. Could you please put me in right direction?[image]

Please ask for more information you need from me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is not because of Mule component.There may be several other reasons at MySQL side.

As you can see that your credentials are processed by MySQL however denied.This suggests that the problem may not be directly 
related with credentials because if credentials were wrong the error would have been different then denied.

When credentials are denied, the problem is mostly related with:

- Permission issue - Solution >> Grant permission to use "db_name" from "Localhost"
- Your connection string looks fine but sometimes string encoding result this error
- Some installed components are interfering with MySql -> Check the components installation

Also

LOCALHOST and "machine name" aren't the same to MySQL.

I'd check from the command line that you can connect to localhost:

```
mysql --user=<user_name> --password db_name

Enter password: your_password
```

If it fails, connect and run this with the appropriate permissions:

```
create user db_name@localhost identified by 'db_name';
grant select on <user_name>.* to db_name@localhost;
```

Comment: I can connect to localhost using mysql --user=<user_name> --password db_name.  :D what could be further issue?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind :) I found the solution although did not find what the problem was only suspecting that the root was not having any schema privileges ( as shown by MySQL Workbench GUI). 
Earlier I was using command line with which I am not well versed; after struggling a little I downloaded MySQL workbench and added one more user with all administrative and schema privileges and used that to connect with Database connector and God Damn!! it's working.